# Mysql find a table in from another table record and find a specific record in this table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a new in Mysql and I have a complicated problem:
I have a table with "Shops" name in this table there is a ShopID column. The records look like this:
Shop_001
Shop_002...

Every "shopID" refer to a new table with this name, for example there is a table with Shop_0001 name. In this table there is "partnumber" column which mean the parts which are available in this shop.

I send a specific part number to sql server and I want to check all shops in the "Shops" table and return a rows in the "Shop_xxxx" tables which has this specific partnumber.
Unfortunately I have no idea how do I get start on this. Can anybody help me give some instruction or anything on this?

Comment: Give us SQL fiddle with sample data instead of text explanation

Comment: Your design sounds flawed. You shouldn't have a new table for every shop. You should have one table with all the parts for all the shops, and each row in this parts table should have a shopID to refer to which shop that part belongs in.

I think you should probably look for a basic database tutorial for table design and simple table relationships (this would be a one-to-many relationship or a many-to-many relationship, depending on your situation).

Comment: The problem is the same part can be available in a many shops thats why I think I cannot handle this in one table.

Comment: If one part can be found in many shops, that's fine. You'll need to create an inventory table that has columns for shops and parts.  A shop that has 5 parts would be listed 5 times (one for each part). Another shop with 3 parts would be listed another 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for a many to many relationship.  so you just need 3 tables

1 table is the list of shops
1 table is the list of products
and 1 table is the list of which shops have which products.  like this

```
table1
    id|shops
    ------
    1  shop1
    2  shop2
    3  shop3


table2
    id|products
    ------
    1  prod1
    2  prod2
    3  prod3
    4  prod4
    5  prod5

table3
    id|shop_id|prod_id
    -------------------
    1   2        3
    2   2        1
    3   2        2
    4   1        3
    5   1        4
    6   1        5
    7   3        2
```

So for every time a product is added to a shop, an entry is added in table3.  This will allow you to query by shops or by products, and you will only ever need 3 tables.

google querying many to many relationships for how to get the list of products for shop1 or the list of shops that have product4  etc.

Comment: this is a much better way to do it. If you implement your design with the original way of thinking about it (in your original question), you're going to be in a world of hurt later on down the road.